# I want to save an ID from a table to another table using asp.net mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem in my project ASP.NET MVC 5 on CREATE ACTION. Here's my code :

**Models**

Members:

```
  public partial class Member
   {
   public Member()
    {
        this.Acc_Transactions = new HashSet<Acc_Transactions>();
        this.Addresses12 = new HashSet<Addresses1>();
        this.BankingDetails = new HashSet<BankingDetail>();
        this.Contacts = new HashSet<Contact>();
        this.TalentCommitments = new HashSet<TalentCommitment>();
        this.Pledges = new HashSet<Pledge>();
    }

    public int m_id { get; set; }
    public int title_id { get; set; }
    public string initial { get; set; }
    public string fname { get; set; }
    public string lname { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> dob { get; set; }
    public string maritial { get; set; }
    public string religion { get; set; }
    public string occupation { get; set; }
    public string company { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Memtype_Id { get; set; }
    public string employed { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> reg_date { get; set; }
    public string AccNumb { get; set; }
    public string Hnumber { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Active { get; set; }
    public string AgeGrp { get; set; }
    public int h_id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> postal_addid { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> phys_addid { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> maritialid { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> PlndGv { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Acc_Transactions> Acc_Transactions { get; set; }
    public virtual Addresses1 Addresses1 { get; set; }
    public virtual Addresses1 Addresses11 { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Addresses1> Addresses12 { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<BankingDetail> BankingDetails { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    public virtual Head Head { get; set; }
    public virtual Maritial Maritial1 { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TalentCommitment> TalentCommitments { get; set; }
    public virtual MemberType MemberType { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Pledge> Pledges { get; set; }
    public virtual Title Title { get; set; }
}
```

}

Heads:

```
public partial class Head
 {
    public Head()
    {
        this.Addresses1 = new HashSet<Addresses1>();
        this.Members = new HashSet<Member>();
    }

    public int h_id { get; set; }
    public string h_initials { get; set; }
    public string fname { get; set; }
    public string lname { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string cell { get; set; }
    public string cell2 { get; set; }
    public string tel_h { get; set; }
    public string tel_w { get; set; }
    public string fax { get; set; }
    public string h_no { get; set; }
    public int title_id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> active { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Addresses1> Addresses1 { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Member> Members { get; set; }
    public virtual Title Title { get; set; }
}
```

}

**ViewModel**

```
 public class MembersViewModel
{
    public int m_id { get; set; }
    public string titles { get; set; }
    public string initial { get; set; }
    public string fname{ get; set; }
    public string lname { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> dob { get; set; }
    public string maritials { get; set; }
    public string religion { get; set; }
    public string occupation { get; set; }
    public string company { get; set; }
    public string note { get; set; }
    public string employed { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> regdate { get; set; }
    public string accNumb { get; set; }
    public string hnumber { get; set; }
    public string agegroup { get; set; }
    public string plandGv { get; set; }
    public string cell { get; set; }
    public string tel_h { get; set; }
    public int title_id { get; set; }
    public string flatName { get; set; }
    public string flatNo { get; set; }
    public string strname { get; set; }
    public string strNo { get; set; }
    public string suburb { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string tel_w { get; set; }
    public string fax { get; set; }
    public string cell2 { get; set; }
    public bool active { get; set; }
    public string province { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
    public int? postalcode { get; set; }
    public string zone { get; set; }
    public bool isHa { get; set; }
    public int addtype { get; set; }
    public int PhysAddID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> phys_addid { get; set; }
    public int h_id { get; set; }
    public int maritialid { get; set; }
    public int Memtype_Id { get; set; }

}
```

}

**Controller**

Get Action:

```
  public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.phys_addid = new SelectList(db.Addresses1, "PhysAddID", "strNo");
        ViewBag.postal_addid = new SelectList(db.Addresses1, "PhysAddID", "strNo");
        ViewBag.h_id = new SelectList(db.Heads, "h_id", "h_initials");
        ViewBag.maritialid = new SelectList(db.Maritials, "Maritialid", "MaritialType");
        ViewBag.Memtype_Id = new SelectList(db.MemberTypes, "Memtype_Id", "Type");
        ViewBag.title_id = new SelectList(db.Titles, "title_id", "Titles");
        return View();
    }
```

Post Action:

```
public ActionResult Create(MembersViewModel memberViewModel)
    {
        var client = new Member
        {
            fname = memberViewModel.fname,
            lname = memberViewModel.lname,
            initial = memberViewModel.initial,
            title_id = memberViewModel.title_id,
            dob = memberViewModel.dob,
            maritial = memberViewModel.maritials,
            religion = memberViewModel.religion,
            occupation = memberViewModel.occupation,
            company = memberViewModel.company,
            Note = memberViewModel.note,
            employed = memberViewModel.employed,
            reg_date = memberViewModel.regdate,

            AccNumb = memberViewModel.accNumb,
            Hnumber = memberViewModel.hnumber,
            Active = memberViewModel.active,
            AgeGrp = memberViewModel.agegroup,
            h_id = memberViewModel.h_id,
        };
        var client1 = new Addresses1();
        var contact = new Contact();
        using (var context = new ParishDBSQLEntities())
        {
            context.Members.Add(client);                
            client1.h_ID = client.h_id;
            client1.strNo = memberViewModel.strNo;
            client1.strname = memberViewModel.strname;
            client1.Suburb = memberViewModel.suburb;
            client1.City = memberViewModel.city;
            client1.Province = memberViewModel.province;
            client1.Country = memberViewModel.country;
            client1.PostalCode = memberViewModel.postalcode;
            client1.zone = memberViewModel.zone;
            client1.flatName = memberViewModel.flatName;
            client1.flatNo = memberViewModel.flatNo;
            client1.IsHa = memberViewModel.isHa;
            client1.AddType = memberViewModel.addtype;
            context.Addresses1.Add(client1);
            contact.Email = memberViewModel.email;
            contact.cell = memberViewModel.cell;
            contact.cell2 = memberViewModel.cell;
            contact.tel_h = memberViewModel.tel_h;
            contact.tel_w = memberViewModel.tel_w;
            contact.fax = memberViewModel.fax;
            contact.m_id = client.m_id;
           context.Contacts.Add(contact);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

my problem is that i want to save a new member on members table but the new member must save a head ID from heads table can you please assist. In details"
H_id is a foreign key to members table from heads tables . The head is already saved, now i want save a new member on members table under the head that already exist in heads table. but on members table i want to save H_id of that particular head."

Comment: Well for starters, personally I would not use `ViewBag` for model data. Its also the wrong use of `ViewBag` that is causing the issue. Post your `MembersViewModel` as well please

Comment: @AbdulG already did post it.

Comment: Ok could you just describe how your system should work? What steps is it suppose to take when creating a `Member`? Does an `h_id` exist before the `Member` is added? It looks like `h_id` is a foreign key in your `Member` table

Comment: Yes h_id already exist on heads table. H_id is a foreign key to members table from heads tables . The head is already saved in heads table, now i want save a new member on members table under the head that already exist in heads table. but on members table i want to save H_id of that particular head."

Comment: How would you reference your `h_id` field? The database needs to be queried and only after `Head` entity is retrieved, can we pass an `h_id` with your model to and from your view

Comment: Normally at the start of your `GET` action, you would do something like `context.Heads.Find(id)` if you have the `h_id` and are trying to retrieve the other properties. Or you could use `Head head = context.Heads.FirstOrDefault(x => x.fname.Equals(string));` in the event you want to compare strings and return an unknown `h_id`. Whats missing, is that you haven't shown any criteria to identify the `h_id` to use

Comment: @AbdulG thats what i want know.

Comment: There's no rush, I am patient, we can work through this. We do need that criteria though

Comment: can you assist me to show that criteria

Comment: Ok well, right now, it doesn't seem as though you have anything that could be unique and referenced through both. One more question, does the new member add his `cell` when filling the form?  or is that already in the DB?

Comment: Yes it does add cell the only thing that exist is details of head and when i save cell for new member i save the cell on contacts table

Comment: I see there is `cell` in your `Head` table as well, is that suppose to populate after the member is added?

Comment: and another thing that can help here abduliG is that i did this on desktop application, the criteria i used on desktop application is that when i save a new member i first search for a head of that paticular member that i want to save. Immediately i display data for head i get the h_id then i save new member

Comment: Thats the criteria I was talking about ninja, but okay, doing it the same as the desktop app you mentioned is way beyond the scope of this question. I will write up an answer assuming that the member will be adding his cell number, which is already available to be referenced from the `Head` table

Comment: In other words, the cell number will be used to locate the members record in the `Head` table. Is that fine?

Comment: look this my screenshot mybe you will understand better

Comment: my bad i cant post my screen shot  i need to have 10 rep

Comment: NO, it cant be cell number cause in some fields cell number is null

Comment: Well if it is not cell number, it will need to something else, that is unique

Comment: how about fname or lname ?

Comment: Names should never be used as you would most likely find duplicates. However, if you insist, il update my answer in an hour or 2, I just need to run out for abit

Comment: ok  but its working this one but i think i should use the criteria that i used on my desktop application

Comment: That will first search the head and then i add a new member.

Comment: Can u please give me ideas what should i do to achieve that ?

Comment: For reference purposes, start a new question, you could comment the  link here so I can easily access it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From our comments, in your `Post` action I would suggest using `Bind` for all data that is going to be posted to the DB. You just need to mention field names (for the example I only mentioned 3 fields).

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "fname,lname,cell")]MembersViewModel memberViewModel)
{
    Head head = context.Heads.FirstOrDefault(x => x.cell.Equals(memberViewModel.cell));
    // now we have a Head entity to reference
    var client = new Member
    {
        fname = memberViewModel.fname,
        lname = memberViewModel.lname,
        initial = memberViewModel.initial,
        title_id = memberViewModel.title_id,
        dob = memberViewModel.dob,
        maritial = memberViewModel.maritials,
        religion = memberViewModel.religion,
        occupation = memberViewModel.occupation,
        company = memberViewModel.company,
        Note = memberViewModel.note,
        employed = memberViewModel.employed,
        reg_date = memberViewModel.regdate,

        AccNumb = memberViewModel.accNumb,
        Hnumber = memberViewModel.hnumber,
        Active = memberViewModel.active,
        AgeGrp = memberViewModel.agegroup,
        h_id = head.h_id,                      // this is where we set Member.h_id
    };
    var client1 = new Addresses1();
    var contact = new Contact();
    using (var context = new ParishDBSQLEntities())
    {
        context.Members.Add(client);                
        client1.h_ID = head.h_id;               // using head entity as reference again
        client1.strNo = memberViewModel.strNo;
        client1.strname = memberViewModel.strname;
        client1.Suburb = memberViewModel.suburb;
        client1.City = memberViewModel.city;
        client1.Province = memberViewModel.province;
        client1.Country = memberViewModel.country;
        client1.PostalCode = memberViewModel.postalcode;
        client1.zone = memberViewModel.zone;
        client1.flatName = memberViewModel.flatName;
        client1.flatNo = memberViewModel.flatNo;
        client1.IsHa = memberViewModel.isHa;
        client1.AddType = memberViewModel.addtype;
        context.Addresses1.Add(client1);
        contact.Email = memberViewModel.email;
        contact.cell = memberViewModel.cell;
        contact.cell2 = memberViewModel.cell;
        contact.tel_h = memberViewModel.tel_h;
        contact.tel_w = memberViewModel.tel_w;
        contact.fax = memberViewModel.fax;
        contact.m_id = client.m_id;              // NB
       context.Contacts.Add(contact);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

There is one major issue here. `client.m_id` = 0. This is because we haven't manually set the value for `m_id`. Even if `m_id` is DB generated. The id will only be given to the entity on context.SaveChanges.

To resolve this, if your `m_id` field is DB generated, you can copy `context.SaveChanges();` just under `client1.h_ID = head.h_id;` then before setting the values for `contact`, initialize an instance of a `Member`.

Again, here I think you should add a `cell` field to `Member` so you can reference it like this:

```
Member temp = context.Member.FirstOrDefault(x => x.cell.Equals(memberViewModel.cell));
```

You can then change this line `contact.m_id = client.m_id;` to this `contact.m_id = temp.m_id`;

Hope this helps you

Comment: thank you for your time this one is working but this one is not doing what i want.

Comment: There was too much to put in one answer. This is only to address the original question : "my problem is that i want to save a new member on members table but the new member must save a head ID from heads table"

Comment: please find the link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26699484/how-to-search-a-head-then-save-a-new-member-under-that-head-in-asp-net-mvc-5

Comment: cna you please check my link abdulG

Answer (score 0):

You have to create ViewModel which will contains Dates what You need from both tables.
In Cotroler You crate new Object type Member, and load by LINQ or EF Head ID to Your model.

```
Member p1=new Member();
p1.Name=ViewModel.Name; etc..
```

after that,
In secound table You add p1.ID in secound table

```
    context.Add(p1)
    context.saveChanges();
    Head.Id=p1.ID;
```

Comment: H_id is a foreign key to members table  from heads tables . The head  is already saved, now i want save a new member on members table under the head that already exist in heads table. but on members table i want to save H_id of that particular head.