# How to search a head then save a new member under that head in asp.net mvc 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i have this screen shot of my project on desktop application but now i want to do it on my asp.net mvc 5 application. Please see the picture shown below:

[image]

**Members**

```
 public partial class Member
  {
   public Member()
    {
    this.Acc_Transactions = new HashSet<Acc_Transactions>();
    this.Addresses12 = new HashSet<Addresses1>();
    this.BankingDetails = new HashSet<BankingDetail>();
    this.Contacts = new HashSet<Contact>();
    this.TalentCommitments = new HashSet<TalentCommitment>();
    this.Pledges = new HashSet<Pledge>();
}

public int m_id { get; set; }
public int title_id { get; set; }
public string initial { get; set; }
public string fname { get; set; }
public string lname { get; set; }
public Nullable<System.DateTime> dob { get; set; }
public string maritial { get; set; }
public string religion { get; set; }
public string occupation { get; set; }
public string company { get; set; }
public string Note { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> Memtype_Id { get; set; }
public string employed { get; set; }
public Nullable<System.DateTime> reg_date { get; set; }
public string AccNumb { get; set; }
public string Hnumber { get; set; }
public Nullable<bool> Active { get; set; }
public string AgeGrp { get; set; }
public int h_id { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> postal_addid { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> phys_addid { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> maritialid { get; set; }
public Nullable<bool> PlndGv { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<Acc_Transactions> Acc_Transactions { get; set; }
public virtual Addresses1 Addresses1 { get; set; }
public virtual Addresses1 Addresses11 { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Addresses1> Addresses12 { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<BankingDetail> BankingDetails { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
public virtual Head Head { get; set; }
public virtual Maritial Maritial1 { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<TalentCommitment> TalentCommitments { get; set; }
public virtual MemberType MemberType { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Pledge> Pledges { get; set; }
public virtual Title Title { get; set; }
    }
    }
```

**Heads**

```
public partial class Head
   {
    public Head()
{
    this.Addresses1 = new HashSet<Addresses1>();
    this.Members = new HashSet<Member>();
}

public int h_id { get; set; }
public string h_initials { get; set; }
public string fname { get; set; }
public string lname { get; set; }
public string Email { get; set; }
public string cell { get; set; }
public string cell2 { get; set; }
public string tel_h { get; set; }
public string tel_w { get; set; }
public string fax { get; set; }
public string h_no { get; set; }
public int title_id { get; set; }
public Nullable<bool> active { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<Addresses1> Addresses1 { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Member> Members { get; set; }
public virtual Title Title { get; set; }
   }
```

**ViewModel**

```
 public class MembersViewModel
  {
public int m_id { get; set; }
public string titles { get; set; }
public string initial { get; set; }
public string fname{ get; set; }
public string lname { get; set; }
public string email { get; set; }
public Nullable<System.DateTime> dob { get; set; }
public string maritials { get; set; }
public string religion { get; set; }
public string occupation { get; set; }
public string company { get; set; }
public string note { get; set; }
public string employed { get; set; }
public Nullable<System.DateTime> regdate { get; set; }
public string accNumb { get; set; }
public string hnumber { get; set; }
public string agegroup { get; set; }
public string plandGv { get; set; }
public string cell { get; set; }
public string tel_h { get; set; }
public int title_id { get; set; }
public string flatName { get; set; }
public string flatNo { get; set; }
public string strname { get; set; }
public string strNo { get; set; }
public string suburb { get; set; }
public string city { get; set; }
public string tel_w { get; set; }
public string fax { get; set; }
public string cell2 { get; set; }
public bool active { get; set; }
public string province { get; set; }
public string country { get; set; }
public int? postalcode { get; set; }
public string zone { get; set; }
public bool isHa { get; set; }
public int addtype { get; set; }
public int PhysAddID { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> phys_addid { get; set; }
public int h_id { get; set; }
public int maritialid { get; set; }
public int Memtype_Id { get; set; }

 }
}
```

**Index Action:**

```
  public ActionResult Index()
    {
        HeadVM list = new HeadVM()
        {
            data = new List<Heads>()
        };
        var AllHeads = db.Heads;
        foreach (var item in AllHeads)
        {
            if (item != null)
            {
                list.data.Add(new Heads
                {
                    h_id = item.h_id,
                    fname = item.fname,
                    lname = item.lname,
                });
            }
        }
        return View(list);
    }
```

My problem is that I want to first search heads details, then after i searched the heads details when i click a particular head it must only display the h_id not all details then i save a new member under that H_id. Please help.

Comment: Hi ninja, will the user only need to see `h_id`, `title` and `firstname` fields on the initial view? in order to select their `Head`?

Comment: Hi abdulG, yes but after the user selected the head it must display only the h_id then i save a new member under that h_id

Comment: and last name AbdulG

Comment: Sorry about these late replies, a bit caught up with my own work. For now, update thread with your DB models.. we need something to work from

Comment: ok ke i already did that find them on top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets start with an initial view we will call `Index`. So we will need a `ViewModel` for it, lets call it `HeadVM`

```
[Serializable]
public class HeadVM
{
    public List<Heads> data { get; set; }      
}
public class Heads
{
    public int h_id { get; set; }
    public string fname { get; set; }
    public string lname { get; set; }
}
```

I am assuming we will just be populating the entire initial view with a complete list of all the heads.

Now for our action:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    HeadVM list = new HeadVM()
        {
            data = new List<Heads>()
        };
        var AllHeads = context.Heads;
        foreach (var item in AllHeads)
        {
            if (item != null)
            {
                list.data.Add(new Heads
                {
                    h_id = item.h_id,
                    fname = item.fname,
                    lname = item.lname,
                });
            }
        }
        return View(list);
}
```

This will return a list of `Heads` to your `Index` view, where you can simply show and access each `Head` with a button. In this case I use a table as I find it is the simplest to display a list:

```
@model ...HeadVM
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <th>HeaderID</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <td></td>
</tr>
@foreach(var item in Model.data)
<tr>
    <td>@item.h_id</td>
    <td>@item.fname</td>
    <td>@item.lname</td>
    <td>@Html.ActionLink("Add Member", "Create", "Home", new { id = item.h_id }, new { target = "_blank" })</td>
</tr>
```

This will give a list of heads, with a button in each row "Add member"(As I don't know exactly how your relationships work, I am going to assume `Head` to `Member` is in 1:Many relationship. Purely for a more functional system. Also, because of `new { target = "_blank"}`, the Create view will start in new window.

Then we start on our `[HttpGet]` action:

```
public ActionResult Create(int id)
    {
        var temp = context.Heads.Find(id);
        MembersViewModel tmp = new MembersViewModel
        {
            h_id = temp.h_id,
        };
        return View(tmp);
    }
```

This will now return the a model to your 'Create' view with prepopulated `h_id` field. There shouldn't be much trouble from here regarding adding a new member with the prepopulated `h_id` that we worked through in your previous answer [Saving ID from another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26669740/i-want-to-save-an-id-from-a-table-to-another-table-using-asp-net-mvc-5/26671649?noredirect=1#comment42013989_26671649/)

This is more of a guideline than an exact copy paste answer, as I don't fully understand your system. Also, I see `Title` actually comes from another table, so the value isn't available directly from the 'Head' table, except an `int` value `ID`. This was my reason for not referencing the `Title` field.

Hope this helps you with your project

Comment: abduliG i'm struggling on the view code i should create a new view razor or where should i put that code of view ?

Comment: which view? The index view I gave the code for. You will just need to make minor changes to it for the location of your model

Comment: Since your `MembersViewModel` has so many properties, you may be better off just scaffolding the view and action. It will save you alot of time, then you can edit it accordingly

Comment: Sorry this setup actually uses 2 views, an `Index` view to select the head and a `Create` view to add the `Member`

Comment: @foreach (var item in Model.data)
        <tr>
            <td>@item.h_id</td>
            <td>@item.fname</td>
            <td>@item.lname</td>
            <td>@Html.ActionLink("Add Member", "Create", "Home", new { id = item.h_id }, new { target = "_blank" })</td>
        </tr>

Comment: Yes, i forget to right an error i ve an on data and item

Comment: I find an error here in my controller index: foreach (var item in AllHeads) this is my error "An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code " and "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections."

Comment: Check your webconfig file. Are the connection strings correct? If you paste them here, make sure to censor out your UN and PW

Comment: Ok I think you can remove your connect string comment. Next, have a look at the InnerException from the detail of this error. Whats it say?

Comment: my error is on data "'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<parishV3.Models.HeadVM>' does not contain a definition for 'data' and no extension method 'data' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<parishV3.Models.HeadVM>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: i dont understand you abdul can you please expand your explaination

Comment: abdulG can u please check my answer

Comment: Mmmm, ok so lets start with some debugging. Add a breakpoint to `return View(list);` and then check the `length` of `data`. You will also be able to see entities that make up `data`. If your using Visual Studio, then you can just mouse over the variable you wont to check once the breakpoint is hit

Comment: i did add breakpoint in my controller code  it is working fine no errors but my error is on my view where "@foreach (var item in Model.data)"

Comment: When the breakpoint was hit, could you see what was inside of the Model's `data`? The error may be on the View, but its being caused elsewhere

Comment: When i run the project it goes straight to my view error wen i added the break point

Comment: Even before running my project data on my view is having an error

Comment: model Enumerable<parishV3.Models.HeadVM> don't you think the error is here?

Comment: data is fine now im continuing nw with add new.

Comment: thank you very much for your time and patience. There are few people that have patience like you. its working now.

Comment: can you please check this i ve, if u can assit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27444222/how-to-save-an-id-for-a-dropdownlist-using-angular-js?noredirect=1#comment43327828_27444222