# How to Save an id for a dropdownlist using angular js?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs, api

I have a problem in my project using Angularjs. Here is my code:

**Controller**

```
     // GET: api/CustomerLists/5


    [ResponseType(typeof(CustomerList))]
    public IHttpActionResult GetCustomerList(int id)
    {

        var data = (from cust in db.CustomerLists
            join call24 in db.CallingList4
                on cust.CustID equals call24.CustID

            where cust.CustID == id

            select new CustomerVM
            {
                CustID = cust.CustID,
                Customer = cust.Customer,
                Call4ID = call24.Call4ID,
                Wk1WebID = call24.Wk1WebID,
                Wk1OrdID = call24.Wk1OrdID



            }).First();

        return Ok(data);

    }



  // PUT: api/CustomerLists/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
    public IHttpActionResult PutCustomerList(CustomerVM vm)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var cust = db.CustomerLists.Find(vm.CustID);
            var call4 = db.CallingList4.Find(vm.Call4ID);

            cust.Customer = vm.Customer;
            cust.ContactName = vm.ContactName;

            call4.Wk1OrdID = vm.Wk1OrdID;
            call4.Wk1WebID = vm.Wk1WebID;


            db.CustomerLists.Attach(cust);
            db.Entry(cust).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.CallingList4.Attach(call4);
            db.Entry(call4).State = EntityState.Modified;

            db.SaveChanges();
        }


        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);


    }
```

**JS**

```
  var EditCtrl = function ($scope, $routeParams, $location, data, $http) {

var id = $routeParams.editId;
$scope.lis = data.get({ id: id });

$scope.selectTest = null;
$scope.testTest = [];

$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/api/OrderStatus/',
    data: { OrderStatID: 1 }
}).success(function(result) {
    $scope.testTest = result;
});


$scope.selectTest1 = null;
$scope.testTest1 = [];

$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/api/WebStatus/',
    data: { WebStatID: 1 }
}).success(function (result1) {
    $scope.testTest1 = result1;
});


$scope.save = function () {
    data.update({ id: id }, $scope.lis, function () {
        $location.path('/');
    });
};
```

**Template**

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="selectTest" ng-model="lis.OrderStatID">
                <option ng-repeat="s in testTest" value="{{s.OrderStatID}}">{{s.OrderStatus}}</option>
            </select>
```

**View Model**

```
public class CustomerVM
{
    public int CustID { get; set; }
    public string Customer { get; set; }
    public int? Priority { get; set; }
    public string ContactName { get; set; }
    public string ContactNumber { get; set; }
    public int Call4ID { get; set; }
    public int? Wk1WebID { get; set; }
    public int? Wk1OrdID { get; set; }
    public int? OrderStatId { get; set; }
    public string OrderStatus { get; set; }
}
```

}

When I try to update, the CustomerList details update just fine, but the CallingList4 details return null when I select a status and I try to save an ID. How do I save the ID from another table to the main table which is callingList24? please help

**UPDATED**

[image]

> look at this screen shot it does select from the table, but the problem it does not want to save an id to another table.

Comment: It's not really clear what the problem is from your description and code. For example your angular controller does not save anything at all. Post the JS that saves the data and example of the JSON and what this desierialses to in your controller.

Comment: Check out the select example on the AngularJS website: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

Comment: it does save.. the save method in the js does the saving.. It saves the customerList but when I try to save the CallingList4, the ID from the dropdown it saves null...

Answer (score 0):

I see it is a design issue rather than code issue

You need to redesign your ViewModel to include subclasses for properties like Status and CallingList

Then pass the value using expression like {{s.Status.ID}} and so on for all composed properites

Comment: @mGounda can you please assist with design

Comment: @ninjaXnado, I recommend you check [this useful hands-on lab](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/build-a-single-page-application-(spa)-with-aspnet-web-api-and-angularjs). this combines ASP.NET MVC, WebAPI, and AngularJS in a simple example that covers your case and more